# Parse PFUser.currentUser returns nil - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I am logging in my users using Parse. As my app opens my LaunchVieWController determines whether users are already signed in or not:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Make sure cached users don't have to log in every time they open the app
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    println(currentUser)
    if currentUser != nil {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("alreadySignedIn", sender: self)
        }
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSignUpIn", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

If users are already signed in they are taken to the table view described below. If they are not logged in, they are taken to a view in which they can go to the signup view or the login view.

My signup works perfectly fine, and signs up users and then redirects them to the table view.
Here is the signup function (it is in a separate controller from the login function):

```
func processSignUp() {

    var userEmailAddress = emailAddress.text
    var userPassword = password.text

    // Ensure username is lowercase
    userEmailAddress = userEmailAddress.lowercaseString

    // Add email address validation

    // Start activity indicator
    activityIndicator.hidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    // Create the user
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = userEmailAddress
    user.password = userPassword
    user.email = userEmailAddress

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signInToNavigation", sender: self)
            }

        } else {

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
                self.message.text = "\(message)"
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

My login function looks like so:

```
@IBAction func signIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var userEmailAddress = emailAddress.text
    userEmailAddress = userEmailAddress.lowercaseString
    var userPassword = password.text

   PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userEmailAddress, password:userPassword) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signInToNavigation", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            if let message: AnyObject = error!.userInfo!["error"] {
                self.message.text = "\(message)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After users log in they are sent to a table view. In that table view I am trying to access the current user object in the following function, as I want to load different data based on who the user is:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"MyClass")
    query.whereKey("userID", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    return query
}
```

When I try to log in with a user I get thrown the following error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". It seems like the `PFUser.currentUser()` object is nil.

When users are sent to the table view after **signing up** the PFUser.currentUser() object is set and works perfectly.

My guess is that this is because of the fact that the `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground` is happening in the background and that my query is trying to get the `PFUser.currentUser()` object before it has been loaded. Is there anyway I can work around this issue? In the table view the value of `PFUser.currentUser()` is needed to load the table data. Can I somehow make sure that `PFUser.currentUser()` gets assigned with the current user object before the function gets called (for example, by not loading in users in the background thread)?

All help is much appreciated!

**EDIT: I've updated this post with some more of my code to help highlight any bug that I may be missing.**

Comment: Have you tested if it's called before the login response handler?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to test for this, but I've added a breakpoint here: http://i.imgur.com/cYZLtNj.png and the error persists (It doesn't stop at the breakpoint but throws an the same error as before in the table view). This seems really odd as I thought the  `signInToNavigation` segue would have to execute before any code on in that view would execute.

Comment: It would, unless there is a different way to get to it. Logging is perhaps a better potion than breakpoints at this stage

Comment: I've updated my post with more (hopefully) relevant code. When I sign up users the PFUser.currenUser object gets set and everything works. Can't wrap my head around why this is not working with the login function though.

Comment: You should really use the form `if let user = user {` instead of `if user != nil {` to check that the user is available, but other than that I can't see anything wrong. Have you logged the returned user and error in the login response?

Comment: Thank you for that. In order to log my currentUser in the login response I have to remove the reference to `PFUser.currentUser` in the table view (as that executes before for some reason. When I log the returned user like so: http://i.imgur.com/C6yjqJv.png I get back a valid user object. 

When I do not remove the reference in the table view, but log it before it gets called, it gets logged as nil.

Comment: The current user should be updated before the completion block is called. You could try a dispatch after instead of async just to test, though it shouldn't change anything. Alternate is to store the returned user yourself...

Comment: I seem to have found something, although I am not sure what is causing it. When I set the segue to dispatch after 10 seconds with this code:
http://i.imgur.com/LefgliN.png

It loads the table view directly, and then logs "test" after ten seconds. For some reason it seems like the segue is not what is initiating the next view.

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that this problem appeared because the segue `signInToNavigation` was wired from the Login-button, instead from the login view controller itself. This resulted in the segue being executed before the login function was executed, and therefore the `PFUser.currentUser()`object was not yet assigned when the table view loaded. I solved this by rewiring the segues. Stupid slip-up on my side.

Thanks to Ryan Kreager and Wain for taking time to help me figure out this issue!

Comment: Huzzah! Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if `PFUser.currentUser() != nil` instead to make sure it's being set right after login. If it's not being set right off the bat, you know there is a deeper login problem.

Also, try removing the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){` wrapper around your call to the segue.

It's unnecessary (logInWithUsernameInBackground already returns to the main thread) and I have a hunch that it's creating a racing condition where the local object is not being set first because Parse can't do any post-call cleanup since you're going right for the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The error (`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`) still gets thrown if I remove the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){`.

Comment: I've updated my post with more (hopefully) relevant code. When I sign up users the `PFUser.currenUser` object gets set and everything works. Can't wrap my head around why this is not working with the login function though.

Comment: I'll test it out and see if I can find the bug!

Comment: Updated my answer - try checking if `PFUser.currentUser() != nil` in addition to your check of `if user != nil` to make sure it's being set right after login.

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks for your help!